# Find all the unique minimum elements for power set of vectors

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of $K$ vectors: $G = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_K\}, v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

And define a minimum operation of vectors $M(v): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ as the smallest component in vector $v$. And we define $M(\emptyset) = 0$.

Is there any efficient way to enumerate this set $\{ M(\sum_{v \in S} v)| S\subseteq G\}$ ?

For more context, my real goal is to find the minimum of $\{ M(\sum_{v \in S} v) + M(\sum_{v \in S^C} v)| S\subseteq G\}$.

$S^C$ is the complement of $S$ under $G$.